# PyGame PGU Updating/Repainting Widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, pgu

I'm using Phil's PyGame Utilities (PGU). I have an area that needs to display a changing scrollable list of variables. It's a debug window that should be showing live updates to variables as they change. I have tried doing this with several different widgets and several different ways, but I am having a problem with the scroll bar locking up when I update the widget in the update loop.

My original idea was to place labels in the list, then, change the labels and call either an update or repaint function, but I cant quite seem to get it to work. To get it to work I was completely clearing the widget I was using and just re-adding all the labels each update loop. This causes issues with the scrollbar and hurts my frame rate.

Here is how I thought it should work:

```
self.l = gui.List(width = self.config['uiwidth']-10, height = self.config['height']-230)
self.add(self.l, 5, 255)

self.label = gui.Label("UNCHANGED",align=-1)

    if self.firstTimeSelectingBot == True:
        for i in range(len(dbot.customDebugVariableList)):
            self.l.add(self.label, value = i)
        self.firstTimeSelectingBot = False
    self.label = gui.Label("CHANGED",align=-1)
    self.label.repaint()
```

It adds a label to the list, and then, changes the label. I thought calling repaint would repaint the label to display the new label, but nothing changes. I have tried this with tables and lists, but the only way I can get it to display is buy completely clearing the list/table and re-adding everything which causes scrollbar and framerate problems.

Any help or ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Pgu's documentation is rather vague, but I think you should look into the "next" function built into the widget object. This might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use label.set_text to change the text on the label. So using your code as an example

```
self.l = gui.List(width = self.config['uiwidth']-10, height = self.config['height']-230)
self.add(self.l, 5, 255)

self.label = gui.Label("UNCHANGED",align=-1)

    if self.firstTimeSelectingBot == True:
        for i in range(len(dbot.customDebugVariableList)):
            self.l.add(self.label, value = i)
        self.firstTimeSelectingBot = False
    self.label.set_text("CHANGED")
```

You will note however that the alignment was taken out. Label.set_text fails when you put it in however the alignment set when label was created stays so as long as you don't need to change that this works. Take a look at pgu/gui/basic.py lines 96-129 for the label class itself which is how I figured this out (I also was looking for the answer on my own).